# Mac Lane's Planarity Criterion Proof

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, vector-spaces, plane-curves, planar-graphs

Given a graph $G$, we denote $\mathcal{C}(G)$ its cycle space. We say that a basis $B$ of $\mathcal{C}(G)$ is a *$2$-basis* if every element of $B$ is a cycle and every edge of $G$ belongs to at most two of these cycles. I need to prove the following implication of Mac Lane's planarity criterion:

> Let $G$ be a planar graph. Then $\mathcal{C}(G)$ has a $2$-basis.

I've looked for a proof in books and articles, but I couldn't find anything convincing. They're either restricting the hypotheses or giving the result for granted. I've read one should pick as elements of the $2$-basis the boundaries of the faces of $G$, but these are not necessarily cycles! One can easily find an example in which the boundary of a face is not a cycle.

[image]

My idea to overcome this is to observe that the boundary of a face $f$ decomposes $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \partial f$ in $k+2 \geq 2$ connected components, one of which is $f$, one is unbounded and not interesting for me, whereas the other components contain some subgraphs $H_1,\dots,H_k$ of $G$. We do not consider $\partial f$ when constructing a $2$-basis, but rather the symmetric difference of $\partial f,\partial f_1,\dots,\partial f_k$, where $f_1,\dots,f_k$ are the external faces of $H_1,\dots,H_k$ considered as standalone graphs, not as subgraphs of $G$, but with the same embedding in the plane. In the previous photo, we have an example with $k=1$.

This idea however is driving me crazy since proving that the boundary of $f$ induces such a decomposition of the plane is not trivial at all (yes, this is where my recent questions
[Possible corollary of Jordan's curve theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4190272/possible-corollary-of-jordans-curve-theorem/4190402?noredirect=1#comment8712464_4190402) and [Corollary of Jordan's curve theorem, generalized](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4199056/corollary-of-jordans-curve-theorem-generalized?noredirect=1&lq=1) come from). This is why I am asking you to please provide me with a working proof, or at least a reference, with a cleaner approach.

Comment: Have you tried reading section 5 of Mac Lane's paper? http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm28/fm2814.pdf  Even in the introduction, he acknowledges that "each region is bounded by one or more circuits" and so some of these circuits must be omitted.

Comment: I saw that and it looked like the hypothesis of non-separable graph was restrictive, however I've checked more carefully now and I've noticed there is actually no loss of generality. With that said, I will look into this tomorrow and see if it is clear.