# Interior of a Jordan curve contained in the interior of a bigger Jordan curve

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

Let $C_1, C_2$ be two differentiable Jordan curves (the course is on differential geometry, but I think it is not necessary). If $C_1$ is contained in the interior region of $C_2$, how could I prove that the interior region of $C_1$ is contained in the interior region of $C_2$?
[image]
It is intuitively clear (red contained in orange). I have thought of proving it by contradiction, and drawing the situation (second photo) [image] I think that the contradiction would be that both curves have to intersect, which is not possible as $C_1$ is contained in the interior region. However, I don't know how to write it properly.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Jordan curve theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem)?

Comment: @AnCar yes, but how do you apply it?

Comment: Are these supposed to be curves in the plane? How do you define the "interior region" of a Jordan curve? Your solution is likely to depend on the precise definition.

Comment: @MoisheKohan if $C$ is a simple curve, by Jordan curve theorem, $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus C$ has two connected components, one with parity 1 and one with parity 0. The interior region is the one with parity 1

Comment: "Parity" is an unusual terminology. Do you mean the unoriented intersection number with a generic straight half-line or a generic proper map of $[0,\infty)$? If so, just follow the definition. And you should edit your question for clarity, do not leave your reply to comments.

Comment: This is nearly a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4190272/possible-corollary-of-jordans-curve-theorem/ though this question is a bit simpler.  As in that link I'd suggest positively orienting both curves and using basic winding number arguments; differentiability is not needed for the curves.  What OP wants to show is that if $n\big(C_1, p\big) =1$ then $n\big(C_2, p\big) =0$ is impossible-- this is given by my *"clarification for (b)"* argument.  [Note this also implies $p \not\in [C_2]$ i.e. image of $C_2$, why?]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 'point set topology' argument based on the Jordan curve theorem, without any differentiability assumptions. For clarity, this states that whenever we have a Jordan curve $C$, it separates the plane into a bounded interior region $I$ and an unbounded exterior region $E$. Both $I$ and $E$ are connected and $C$ is the (topological) boundary of both $I$ and $E$, meaning that any open set around a point on $C$ will necessarily intersect both $E$ and $I$.

Some facts first.

*Fact 1:* $C$ is connected. This is immediate since $C$ is the image of a connected set (e.g., a circle) through a continuous map.

*Fact 2:* Let $X$ be a disconnected set and let $Y$ be an arbitrary subset $Y\subset X$. If $X\setminus Y$ still contains points from different connected components of $X$, then $X\setminus Y$ is also disconnected. This can be seen by taking the original partition of $X$ into two disjoint open sets and restricting the two open sets to $X\setminus Y$ (which will stay open w.r.t to the relative topology).

*Fact 3:* If $A$ and $B$ are two connected sets in the plane such that for some point $b\in B$ and any open set $U_b$ containing $b$ we have that $U_b\cap A\neq\varnothing$, then $A\cup B$ is also connected. If this were not true, we would be able to find open sets $O_1\supset A$ and $O_2\supset B$ such that $O_1\cap O_2=\varnothing$ (if either $O_1$ or $O_2$ would 'cut' into either of the sets $A$ and $B$, this would immediately contradict that $A$ and/or $B$ are connected). Now this is clearly not possible since $O_2$ would need to contain the point $b$ and, by openness of $O_2$, a small open set around $b$. Thus $O_2$ will intersect $A$. As a trivial consequence of this fact and the property that $C$ is the topological boundary of $I$ and of $E$, we see that $C\cup I$ and $C\cup E$ are also always connected.

Now let us denote the corresponding interiors and exteriors in the given problem by $I_1, I_2, E_1,E_2$ respectively. The question is does $C_1\subset I_2$ imply $I_1\subset I_2$.

*Claim 1:* $C_1\cap C_2=\varnothing$. This is obvious since $C_1\subset I_2$ and $I_2$ is disjoint from $C_2$.

*Claim 2:* $C_2\cap I_1$ is either empty or all of $C_2$. Indeed, consider the plane without $C_1$, i.e., $I_1\cup E_1$. Since $C_2$ is connected, it cannot lie in two disconnected components of the plane. So if $C_2\cap I_1\neq \varnothing$, then $C_2\subset I_1$ (and obviously $C_2\cap E_1=\varnothing$). Therefore we either have that $C_2\subset I_1$ or $C_2\subset E_1$.

*Claim 3:* The case $C_2\subset I_1$ is impossible. Consider $X:=C_1\cup E_1$, i.e., the plane without $I_1$. Clearly, under the assumptions, $C_2\not\subset C_1\cup E_1$, so $C_2$ was also removed by removing $I_1$. But $C_1\subset X$ and $C_1\subset I_2$, so $I_2\cap X\neq \varnothing$. On the other hand, $X$ is unbounded, so $X\cap E_2\neq\varnothing$ (because $C_2\cup I_2$ is bounded). If we set $A:=X\cap I_2$ and $B:=X\cap E_2$, we get that $X=A\cup B$ since $C_2\not\subset X$. Moreover, both $A$ and $B$ are nonempty. But by *Fact 3* we know that $X$ is connected, but in view of *Fact 2*, $A\cup B$ cannot be connected, contradiction. Thus we necessarily have that $C_2\subset E_1$.

*Claim 4:* $E_2\subset E_1$. Otherwise we can find some point $x\in E_2$ that also lies in $I_1\cup C_1$. But $C_1\subset I_2$, so $x\notin C_1$, meaning that $x\in E_2\cap I_1$. So let us consider the plane without the curve $C_1$, i.e., $I_1\cup E_1$. Since $C_1\subset I_2$, by removing $C_1$ we are not removing any points from $E_2$, meaning that $E_2$ will be a connected subset of $I_1\cup E_1$. Obviously, this is not possible if $E_2$ intersects both $I_1$ and $E_1$ (the latter intersection follows trivially from the fact that $E_2$ is unbounded, so it cannot be contained in $C_1\cup I_1$).

Now we can conclude by noting that we've shown that $C_2\cup E_2\subset E_1$ and therefore $I_1\subset(C_2\cup E_2)^C= I_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Each point $p$ in the exterior of $C_2$ can be connected to infinity by a path $I_p$ lying in the (open) exterior. Since $C_1$ is in the interior component of $C_2$, the path $I_p$ is disjoint from $C_1$.  If any point $p$ in the interior of $C_1$ belonged to the exterior of $C_2$, the path $I_p$ disjoint from $C_1$ would connect $p$ to infinity and hence to the exterior component of $C_1$, contradicting the fact that the interior and the exterior components of $C_1$ are disjoint.  The contradiction proves the result.  Here of course one could replace "infinity" by any point outside of a sufficiently large disk including both Jordan curves.